# How to Update/Merge two huge List<Class> with hundreds of properties in C#, based on common matching Key in most efficient way

Tags: c#, list, merge, automapper, large-data

I have two large set of collection `List<Class>` with hundreds of properties.

e.g. Original Collection `List<OriginalCollection>` and Updated Collection `List<UpdatedColleciton>`

`UpdatedCollection` will contain value in certain columns which most probably will not be part of `OriginalCollection` and `UpdatedCollection` might have certain **KeyColumn [ID Column]** which might not be part of `OriginalCollection`, and I'm receiving thousands of data set in `OriginalCollection` and `UpdatedColletion` will increase in records over a period of time.

I do have a requirement where only null or empty column of `OriginalCollection` should get replaced with matching `UpdatedCollection` value by **ID** and if no matching ID is available then those records should get added in `OriginalCollection` from `UpdatedCollection`.

I tried with `AutoMapper`, where I tried to Update `OriginalCollection` with `UpdatedCollection` based on matching ID, for which I'm unable to find any `AutoMapper configuration` for my sets of above mentioned requirement.

I'm looking for most effective solution which should not impact on performance, thats why I did not go threw typical way of Union and Intersection, as Modal have hundreds of property and thousands of records are there, and as I do have plenty of properties I think library like `AutoMapper` would be good option than writing logic in loop to check value on each column for all thousands of record.

Please suggest any better and performance efficient solution like AutoMapper Configuration or any other .Net inbuilt feature to achieve this scenario.

I also checked with `AutoMapper.Collection` as below from https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection

```
 cfg.CreateMap<OrderItemDTO, OrderItem>().EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.ID == o.ID);
 Mapping OrderDTO back to Order will compare Order items list based on if their ID's match

 Mapper.Map<List<OrderDTO>,List<Order>>(orderDtos, orders);
```

but it has below behavior and not working as expected to my requirement

1. If ID's match will map OrderDTO to Order
2. If OrderDTO exists and Order doesn't add to collection **Not Working for me**
3. If Order exists and OrderDTO doesn't remove from collection **Not Working for me**

Comment: Welcome recent member.  Your question kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu for prompt help, I tried with _AutoMapper.Collection_ but it just replaces Source with Destination without any conditional merge of my posted requirement in question, even after adding below configuration **cfg.CreateMap<Updated, Source>().EqualityComparison((cd, c) => cd.A == c.A);** unable to find any further configuration which can do my job, and such outcome I was already able to achieve with _AutoMapper_ without _AutoMapper.Collection_

Comment: It's whole purpose is to match by id, or smth similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`AutoMapper` is known mapping library and has good documentation as well, but unable to find similar detaild documentation for `AutoMapper.Collection`, I've explored `AutoMapper.Collection` but it was not providing solution as per my requirement.

So, I need to go traditional way.

Prepared differences of collection by `LINQ` query.

```
 var common = original.Where(x => revised.Exists(z => z.ID == x.ID)).ToList();
 var nonCommon = revised.Where(x => !original.Exists(z => z.ID == x.ID)).ToList();

 foreach(var item in common)
 {
      var derived = revised.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == item.ID);

      // Added Extention Method to compare and update property
      var data = item.UpdateProperties(derived);
 }
 common.AddRange(nonCommon);
```

Utilized Reflection to compare objects and update it's value after comparision on property level, for all datatypes.

```
public static T UpdateProperties<T>(this T source, T destination)
{
    Type type = source.GetType();   // Gets Source Object Type
    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();    // Gets Source object Properties

    foreach (var prop in props)     // Iterate threw all properties of source object
    {
        var sourceValue = prop.GetValue(source);    // Get source object value by Property Name
        var destinationValue = prop.GetValue(destination);      // Get destination object value by Property Name, to update source object

        // Update source object property value only if derived object's property has value and source object doesn't
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceValue?.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinationValue?.ToString()))
        {
            prop.SetValue(source, destinationValue);    // Update source object's property with value of derived object
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```